# Probability Question - In a certain family four girls take turns at washing dishes...

Tags: probability, statistics

> In a certain family four girls take turns at washing dishes. Out of a total of four breakages, three were caused by the youngest girl, and she was thereafter called clumsy. Was she justified in attributing the frequency of her breakages to chance?

I'm not sure how to solve the following question. The answer is **13/64** for a girl if the breakage was random and **13/256** for the youngest girl that broke 3 dishes.

Comment: where did you get the question, what are your thoughts what has been tried.

Comment: This question is from "An introduction to probability theory and its applications" by Feller. I don't really understand how to tackle this question.

Comment: I think the $\frac {13}{64}\approx .203$ is the one you want.  The youngest girl can protest "there was a greater than $20\%$ chance that at least three of the breaks would be from one of us so it's no fair pointing at me!"

Comment: In other words, the distribution of breaks, $(3,1,0,0)$ or whatever is perfectly consistent with the assumption of randomness.  Though good luck getting a nickname changed via mathematical reasoning.

Comment: I still don't understand. How did you get 13 and 64?

Comment: I got those values from you.  How did you get them?

Comment: They were at the back of the book lol

Comment: Ok.  Well, what's the question here?  We have one child responsible for three out of four breaks.  Is that surprising or not?  So....compute the probability that at least three of the four breaks come from one child (assuming randomness and independence).  If that comes out very, very low then the young girl deserves her nickname.  If it comes out decently high then she doesn't.

Comment: To illustrate, say she broke all $4$.  The probability (assuming randomness) that one child broke all $4$ is $\frac 4{4^4}$ as there are exactly four ways this could happen (and $4^4$ possible break patterns in total).  That's $\frac 1{4^3}=\frac 1{64}\approx .0156$.  That's pretty low.  I'd conclude that she should either be called Clumsy or Unlucky in that situation.

Comment: But how does the book end up with 13 and what about 13/256?

Comment: Short answer: typo.  It should be $\require{cancel}\cancelto{12}{13}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- count ways to select a girl and three dishes, multiply by the probability that each selection might happen.

The probability that three from four dishes were randomly broken by the same girl is $\tbinom 41\tbinom 43{(\tfrac 14)}^3{(\tfrac 34)}^1$, that is $\tfrac {12}{64}$ or $3/16$.

The probability that three from four dishes were randomly broken by the youngest girl is $\tbinom 43{(\tfrac 14)}^3{(\tfrac 34)}^1$, that is $\tfrac {12}{256}$ or $3/64$.

It rather looks like the answer sheet contains a transcription typo due to all those 1s and 3s.

So, anyway, the conditional probability that the youngest did it, when given three from four dishes were randomly broken by the same girl, is $1/4$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in the book and it's not just a typo. It seems that the provided answers are for another task.

- A: three **or** four breakages are caused by one girl.
- B: three **or** four breakages are caused by the youngest girl.

If we think about the problem as placing four balls (the broken dishes) into four boxes (the girls) then:

- $4^4$ - all possible arrangements.
- $\binom{4}{3}\cdot3$ - а pre-selected girl breaks three dishes.
- $\binom{4}{4}$ - а pre-selected girl breaks four dishes.

and:

- $p(A)=\dfrac{4\cdot\binom{4}{3}\cdot3+4\cdot\binom{4}{4}}{4^4} = \dfrac{13}{64}$
- $p(B)=\dfrac{\binom{4}{3}\cdot3+\binom{4}{4}}{4^4} = \dfrac{13}{256}$